# error al publicar un post en wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Estaba trabajando bien y hace un tiempo me sale este error al publicar un post
Error en la base de datos de WordPress: [Unknown column 'has_ancestors' in 'field list']
INSERT INTO `becyoast_indexable` (`object_id`, `object_type`, `object_sub_type`, `permalink`, `primary_focus_keyword_score`, `readability_score`, `is_cornerstone`, `is_ro

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Esto parece un error de plugin...

Comment: Faltan datos que compartir aca, la BBDD y la query en cuestion.
Primariamente, podes ver que el error dice que desconoce la columna `has ancestors`, todo esto dentro de un `INSERT` que estas utilizando, reformula tu pregunta para mas afondo.

Comment: Por si te sirve aunque está en inglés: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/database-error-unknown-column-has_ancestors/